# hook_form_alter won't save options cck field from custom form

Tags: 7, forms

I have created content type named "site_profile", and form named "add_website_form".
The content type includes cck fields and one of the fields is "field_operators" which is select box field.
I have hooked options of the field to display variable that contains array of specific users with some mechanism.
The hook_form_alter is:

```
function lcm_form_site_profile_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $relevant_users = lcm_get_relevant_users();
    $form['field_operators']['und']['#options'] = $relevant_users;
}
```

Now I am trying to get functionality that stores data into the node through node_save() function from the "add_website_form" (costume form).

the code that supposed to insert the data is:

```
function lcm_add_website_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
    $website_name = $form_state['values']['website_name'];
    $url = $form_state['values']['url'];
    $operators_for_site = $form_state['values']['operators_for_site'];
    lcm_add_website_form_insert_to_db($website_name, $url, $operators_for_site);
}
function lcm_add_website_form_insert_to_db($website_name, $url, $operators_for_site){
    // Create a node object, and add node properties.
    $new_website = new stdClass();

    $new_website->type = 'site_profile';
    $new_website->title = $website_name;
    $new_website->uid = $GLOBALS['user']->uid;
    $new_website->field_url['und'][0]['value'] = $url;
    $new_website->field_operators['und']['value'] = $operators_for_site;
    $new_website->created = strtotime("now");
    $new_website->changed = strtotime("now");
    $new_website->status = 1;
    $new_website->comment = 0;
    $new_website->promote = 0;
    $new_website->moderate = 0;
    $new_website->sticky = 0;
    $new_website->language = 'und';

    node_object_prepare($new_website);
    // Save the node.
    node_save($new_website);
}
```

the problem is that the data that supposed to save on field_operators doesn't save...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, new answer, replace:

```
$new_website->field_operators['und']['value'] = $operators_for_site;
```

with this

```
$new_website->field_operators['und'][0]['value'] = $operators_for_site;
```

Comment: Ok, I have changed that and got an sql error because i should insert the data into: '$new_website->field_operators['und'][0]['field_operators_value']', after change to the above line it worked but the problem now is that the form_state returns an empty array for the $operators_for_site: ' ["operators_for_site"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "0" [1]=> int(0) [2]=> int(0)'